# How to freeze page manually, Page Lifecycle API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, page-lifecycle

I want to debug my page behavior in the `freeze` state by the [Page Lifecycle API post](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/07/page-lifecycle-api) from the `chrome://discards` URL. But I can't find [Freeze] button on [this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKxgr.png)

How I can emulate the `frozen` state of the page and why [Freeze] button not displayed on `chrome://discards`?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any parameters to display this button in current Chrome version (95).

### Workaround

I open [Chrome git](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+log/refs/tags/95.0.4638.75/chrome/browser/resources/discards/discards_tab.html), and find changes for `discards` URL. By the table of Chromium versions, I find last Chrome version (83.0.4103.61) with [Frozen] support, and install it.